# Embedding/excluding certain SPM libraries in specific build configuration

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, swift-package-manager, rxtest

Currently our project are utilising come libraries added through SPM which contains some forbidden symbols, e.g `RxTest`, so before uploading the build to AppStore Connect we have to remove those libraries manually in `Target` -> `Frameworks and Libraries`, but this way we cannot make the upload into an automation process.

Is there any way to configure those libraries to be embedded only in certain build configurations, e.g. `Debug` but not `Release`? Or in order to achieve the same goal, is there any command to remove specific libraries?

Comment: I'm looking for the answer to this as well. @alanlo did you ever figure it out?